# Wolfram Mathematica: Combine two edges in MorphologicalGraph

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, image-manipulation, edges, morphological-analysis

Suppose I have a Morphological Graph as follows:

[image]

and I would like to combine some of these edges which are significantly shorter than the others into a singular edge as indicated in red in the following picture:

[image]

How would I do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you dong this using MS Edge browser? I think the issue is not related with Edge browser. If you think the same then you can remove the 'Edge' tag from question and add a suitable tag. If you are using MS Edge browser then let us know about the steps to produce the issue.

Comment: @deepak-MSFT The [edge] tag isn't for the Edge browser. That's [microsoft-edge].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate your original image before you apply `MorphologicalGraph`. Use [Image Processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageProcessing.html) tools for this. For example, simple application of `Dilation` can shrink a short edge, compare:

[image]